# XSL to flatten XML converted Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, xslt, lxml

I have the following XML Structure:

```
<ml:Meals xmlns:ml="http://www.food.com">
  <ml:Meal>
    <ml:type>lunch</ml:type>
    <ml:main_course>turkey sandwich</ml:main_course>
    <ml:desert ml:Descriptor="cookie">
      <ml:ID ml:type="ID">d47e8bb7876e10001d05b9ca33070215</ml:ID>
    </ml:desert>
  </ml:Meal>
</ml:Meals>
```

I want the converted Pandas dataframe to eventually look like this.

```
+-----+---------------+------+
| type|    main_course|desert|
+-----+---------------+------+
|lunch|turkey sandwich|cookie|
+-----+---------------+------+
```

I have been able to achieve this using the following XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:ml="http://www.food.com">
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ml:Meal">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <desert><xsl:value-of select="ml:desert/@ml:Descriptor"/></desert>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works when using the following command:

```
pandaDf = pd.read_xml(mealSample, namespaces={"ml": "http://www.food.com"}, stylesheet=xsl)
```

My question is, I acticipate there might be additional child nodes within the Meal node that has a `md:Descriptor` that I'll want to pull out and put in the value of the corresponding column in the dataframe. Is there a way to modify the XSL to match on the nested `ml:Descriptor` field value and swap the value out in the way it's currently done for the hard coded `ml:desert` node name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try matching any element that contains `@md:Descriptor` and replace the contents of the element with the value of the attribute.

Example...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ml="http://www.food.com">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[@ml:Descriptor]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ml:Descriptor"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces...

```xml
<ml:Meals xmlns:ml="http://www.food.com">
   <ml:Meal>
      <ml:type>lunch</ml:type>
      <ml:main_course>turkey sandwich</ml:main_course>
      <ml:desert>cookie</ml:desert>
   </ml:Meal>
</ml:Meals>
```

Comment: Ack! Should have known better than to use one of the words that always gives me trouble. Thank you though! This is exactly what I was looking for and does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can parse it directly:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

root = ET.parse("lunch.xml").getroot()
ns = {"ml":"http://www.food.com"}

column = ["type","main_course","desert"]
data = []
for elem in root.findall("ml:Meal", ns):
    ml_type = elem.find("ml:type", ns)
    l_type = ml_type.text
    ml_main_course = elem.find("ml:main_course", ns)
    l_main = ml_main_course.text
    ml_desert = elem.find("ml:desert", ns)
    l_desert = ml_desert.get('{http://www.food.com}Descriptor')
    row = [l_type, l_main, l_desert]
    data.append(row)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     type      main_course     desert
0   lunch  turkey sandwich     cookie
1  dinner            pizza  ice cream
```